# How to test overlay on image hover?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, serenity-bdd

I'm learning test automation and writing tests for Flickr site using Serenity BDD with Page Object pattern.

Test case: when I click on "Explore" link in the main menu, the page should contain photos with label “photo_title by author”. This label appears in overlay when hovering the mouse on the image.

This is part of ExplorePage.class. When running test I get NoSuchElementException.

```
package serenityTest.pages;

import net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.At;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindAll;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.util.List;

import static serenityTest.helpers.Waiter.waitForJSandJQueryToLoad;

@At("https://www.flickr.com/explore")
public class ExplorePage extends PageObject {

    @FindAll({@FindBy(css = ".title")})
    private List<WebElement> photoTitles;

    @FindAll({@FindBy(css = ".attribution")})
    private List<WebElement> photoAuthors;

    @FindAll({@FindBy(xpath = ".//div[@class='view photo-list-photo-view awake']")})
    private List<WebElement> photos;

    public ExplorePage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public ExplorePage checkPhotoLabels() {

        waitForJSandJQueryToLoad();
        WebDriverWait waitForPhotos = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), 10);
        waitForPhotos.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(photos));

        for (WebElement photo : photos) {
            for (WebElement photoTitle : photoTitles) {
                for (WebElement photoAuthor : photoAuthors) {
                    withAction().moveToElement(photo).perform();
                    photoTitle.isDisplayed();
                    photoAuthor.isDisplayed();
                }
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Maybe I'm testing text in overlay in wrong way. Or there are issues with locators (I've tried many variants including XPath).

Will be glad to any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is flaw in the logic. There is 1-to-1 mapping between the photo to it's author and title.

The nested `for` loop used is incorrect. When you use:

```
for (WebElement photo : photos) {
    for (WebElement photoTitle : photoTitles) {
        for (WebElement photoAuthor : photoAuthors) {
            withAction().moveToElement(photo).perform();
            photoTitle.isDisplayed();
            photoAuthor.isDisplayed();
        }
    }
}
```

You are essential checking ALL photo authors for ALL photo titles for EACH photo!!!!

Your loop functions like this for 10 photos...

```
|Photo#|Title#|Author#|
|1     |1     |1      | <-- Author for-loop starts
|1     |1     |2      |
|1     |1     |...    |
|1     |1     |10     |
|1     |2     |1      | <-- Title for-loop increment, Author for-loop restarts
|1     |2     |2      |
|1     |2     |3      |
|1     |...   |...    |
|1     |2     |10     |
|1     |...   |...    |
|1     |10    |10     |
|2     |...   |...    | <-- Photo for-loop increment
|3     |...   |...    |
```

Correct for-loop is:

```
for(WebElement photo : photos) {
    // Get the index of the photo in the list of photos
    int index = photos.indexOf(photo);
    // Get the corresponding title of the photo at index from the list of titles
    WebElement title = photoTitles.get(index);
    // Get the corresponding author of the photo at index from the list of authors
    WebElement author = photoAuthors.get(index);

    // Always build() actions in order to perform()
    withAction().moveToElement(photo).build().perform();
    System.out.println("Photo Title is displayed for photo #" + index + "? " + title.isDisplayed());
    System.out.println("Photo Author is displayed for photo #" + index + "? " + author.isDisplayed());

}
```

Also a note, when using `Actions`, ensure that your end the chained actions with `build().perform()` and not just `perform()`.